# What do DFT band structure plots actually show?

Tags: solid-state-physics, density-functional-theory

In a lot of the literature, we see plots of the energy band structure from DFT simulations. How are these eigen-energies obtained as function of crystal momentum within the DFT framework? Are they the physical quasiparticle energies of the system, or are they just the eigen-energies of the Kohn-Sham equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> we see plots of the energy band structure from DFT simulations. How are these eigen-energies obtained as function of crystal momentum within the DFT framework?

It depends on what specific software program was used to do the calculation.

> Are they the physical quasiparticle energies of the system or
>   just the eigen-energies of the Kohn-Sham equation?

Well, they can't actually be true physical quasiparticle energies... since calculating those would require, e.g., knowledge of the full many-body self-energy.

Some software just calculates the Kohn-Sham eigenvalues and says that those are "close enough" to the quasiparticle energies. Some software will throw in a little "self energy" correction.

But, *typically*, the Kohn-Sham eigenvalues are just assumed to be "close" to the quasiparticle self-energies and the band structure is based on kohn-sham eigenvalues. Of course, this is a horrible assumption in many cases... and a shockingly good assumption in other cases.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to understand why the KS eigenvalues is close to the real case? and in what situation would this assumption becomes invalid?

Comment: The KS eigenvalues are not always close to the real energies. For example, DFT under-estimates the band gaps of many materials by a large amount. This is one of the reasons why people started applying self-energy corrections to DFT. In general, people believe that DFT works better for metals.