# how can DFT calculate band structure

Tags: electronic-band-theory, density-functional-theory

I am trying to understand DFT, and so far i realized that DFT is really concerned with the ground state properties. My question is how can we calculate the band structure of a material using DFT ?

I've seen [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173309/what-do-dft-band-structure-plots-actually-show) it can be done using KS orbitals and interpreting the spectrum as the interacting Hamiltonian spectrum. This is of course not justified mathematically or even physically but is some times a good approximation.

Is there an other way to calculate the band structure using DFT ?

Is TDDFT useful in calculating the band structure ?

DFT calculate the ground state of the Hamiltonian which is again different from the grand canonical ground state even at T=0, how can DFT predict thermodynamic properties since they depend on the later and not on the hamiltonian ground state ?

Comment: 3 years is long to not get an answer, maybe copy and paste here: https://materials.stackexchange.com